# How can I read and write objects from an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, bufferedreader, filewriter

I´m creating an arraylist in my
UserArchive class and add User-objects from my User class:

```
public class UserArchive implements Serializable {
ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();

// Inserts a new User-object
public void regCustomer(User u) {
    list.add(u);
}
```

What is the best way to read and write this list?

I think this is the right way to write it?

```
    public void writeFile() {
    File fileName = new File("testList.txt");
    try{
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName);
        Writer output = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        int sz = list.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++){
            output.write(list.get(i).toString() +"\n");
        }
        output.close();
    } catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Kan ikke lage denne filen");
    }
```

I´ve tried using BufferedReader to read the file, but can't get list.add(line) to work:

```
    public void readFile() {
    String fileName = "testList.txt";
    String line;

    try{
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        if(!input.ready()){
            throw new IOException();
        }
        while((line = input.readLine()) != null){
            list.add(line);
        }
        input.close();
    } catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

I know the problem is that line is a String and should some how be a User. Is the problem that I cant use BufferedReader to do this? If so, how am I suppose to read the file?

Comment: Read [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-an-object-to-file-in-java/) article.

Comment: Or else, just implement `public static User parse(String line) {}`

Comment: By *"I can't get it to work"*, do you mean that `list.add(line)` does not work, or are you having some other problem as well?

Comment: Yes, that what i mean, sorry, and thank you

Comment: Don't throw an exception if the input stream isn't ready. Just read from it! The read will block until the stream is ready.

Comment: Always close your streams/readers/whatever in a finally block. Or use the try-with-resources syntax introduced in Java 7: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: What does "regCustomer" mean? Regular customer? Regulate customer? Region customer? Spell it out :-)

Comment: register customer, thought the list.add was enough;)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is convert each user to csv format provided the user object is not complex.

For example your user class should look like this

```
public class User {

private static final String SPLIT_CHAR = ",";
private String field1;
private String field2;
private String field3;

public User(String csv) {
    String[] split = csv.split(SPLIT_CHAR);
    if (split.length > 0) {
        field1 = split[0];
    }

    if (split.length > 1) {
        field2 = split[1];
    }

    if (split.length > 2) {
        field3 = split[2];
    }
}

/**
 * Setters and getters for fields
 * 
 * 
 */

public String toCSV() {
    //check null here and pass empty strings
    return field1 + SPLIT_CHAR + field2 + SPLIT_CHAR + field3;
}

  }



}
```

While writing the object call
 `output.write(list.get(i).toCSV() +"\n");`
 and when reading you can call 
`list.add(new User(line));`

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a simple User class, like so:

```
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String username;

    // Constructors, etc...

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("#USER $");
        sb.append(id);
        sb.append(" $ ");
        sb.append(username);
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

For an user with `id = 42` and `username = "Dummy"`, the user String representation would be:

```
#USER $ 42 $ Dummy
```

At first glance, your code seems to successfully write these strings to a text file (I haven't tested it yet).
So, the problem lies in reading back the information. This, extracting meaningful information from (in this case) formatted text, is commonly known as *parsing*.

You want to parse this information, from the lines you read.
Adapting your code:

```
BufferedReader input = null;
try {
    input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    String line;
    while((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        list.add(User.parse(line));
    }
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (input != null) { input.close(); }
}
```

Note the subtle difference. I've replaced `list.add(line)` with `list.add(User.parse(line))`. This is where the magic occurs. Let's go on and implement the parsing method.

```
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String username;

    // ...

    public static User parse(String line) throws Exception {
        // Let's split the line on those $ symbols, possibly with spaces.
        String[] info = line.split("[ ]*\\$[ ]*");
        // Now, we must validate the info gathered.
        if (info.length != 3 || !info[0].equals("#USER")) {
            // Here would go some exception defined by you.
            // Alternatively, handle the error in some other way.
            throw new Exception("Unknown data format.");
        }
        // Let's retrieve the id.
        int id;
        try {
            id = Integer.parseInt(info[1]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid id.");
        }
        // The username is a String, so it's ok.
        // Create new User and return it.
        return new User(id, info[2]);
    }
}
```

And you're done!

Comment: Im trying it this way now, but I get an error on InvalidUserDataException, eclipse is asking me to create class InvalidUserDataException or use somthing else, like: InvalidClassException

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that `InvalidUserDataException` would be an exception defined by you, or, instead, use some other way of your liking to handle the error states. I'm updating the answer now.